# Kendo UI MVC Datepicker Format Validation Errors

Tags: validation, kendo-ui, asp.net-mvc-5

I use two types of date formats:

1. MM.yyyy
2. dd.MM.yyyy

I created Editor Templates to handle all my different inputs.

I know that Kendo has some [issues](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/validation#globalized-dates-and-numbers-are-not-recognized-as-valid-when-using-the-kendo-ui-validator) when using date formats that aren't in the selected culture. Thus, I would always get a validation error "The field MEAS DATE must be a date."

I have added the code as they suggested. This DOES fix the format issue. But now for some reason, validation on my TextBox fields break. A Validation Error is shown, although the data entered is correct. The error only shows the little warning icon without any text.

Is there any reason for this happening?

The fields in the Model:

```
[DisplayName("CONTRACT")]
[Required(ErrorMessage="{0} IS REQUIRED")
[UIHint("TextInput")]
[AdditionalMetadata("Class", "green-field")]
[AdditionalMetadata("MaxLength", "10")]
public string ContractNo { get; set; }

[DisplayName("MEAS DATE")]
[UIHint("DateInput")]
[AdditionalMetadata("Class", "green-field")]
[AdditionalMetadata("Format", "dd.MM.yyyy")]
public DateTime MeasurementDate { get; set; }
```

Editor Template for DateTime:

```
@model DateTime?
@{
   var values = ViewData.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues;
   var name = ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName;
 }

@if (values["Class"].ToString().Equals("blue-field"))
{
   @(Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(m => m)
    .Format(values["Format"].ToString())
    .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = values["Class"] })
    .Enable(false)
    .Value(Model)
     )
}
else
{
  @(Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(m => m)
    .Format(values["Format"].ToString())
    .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = values["Class"] + " date" })
    .Value(Model)
    )
}
```

Editor Template for strings:

```
@model string

@{ 
   var values = ViewData.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues;
   var name = ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName;
 }

@if (values["Class"].ToString().Equals("blue-field"))
{
    @(Html.Kendo().TextBoxFor(m => m)
     .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = values["Class"].ToString() + " helper",   @maxlength = values["MaxLength"].ToString() })
     .Enable(false)
     .Value(Model)
    )
}
else
{
    @(Html.Kendo().TextBoxFor(m => m)
       .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = values["Class"].ToString() + " helper", @maxlength = values["MaxLength"].ToString() })
     )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So after fiddling around quite a bit, I came up with a solution.

Since the override function was breaking everything else and the site's culture being the root of the problem, I created my own custom culture and forced the server and client to used the culture.

I used the en-ZA culture supplied by kendo, and edited the date formats to my requirement.

Within my _Layout.cshtml I added the following:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    kendo.culture("en-ZA");           //culture of your choice
    $.validator.addMethod('date',
       function (value, element) {
           return this.optional(element) || kendo.parseDate(value)
       });
  });
</script>
```

I added this line to my web.config:

```
<globalization uiCulture="en-ZA" culture="en-ZA" enableClientBasedCulture="true" ></globalization>
```

And finally, I added Kendo's default validator as per the examples given.

This solved the problem, and as an added benefit, the binding to DateTime fields did not break. (I saw that a date like 01.02.2016 (dd.MM.yyyy) bound as 2 January 2016)

Unfortunately, I still don't know why the bug occurred, but this seemed to have solved it.